# Select Item in Pivot Slicer when A1 Value Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select an item in Pivot Slicer when I change "A1" value.
So when I change the "A1" value to "ABC" the code should look for "ABC" in the Slicer Item and select it.
"A1" value will be same as the items in the slicer.

Here is my try, but doesn't seems to work and doesn't look right :(

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems.Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems(i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") Then
           ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems(i).Selected = True
        Else
           ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
        End If
    Next
End If 
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find something that would works.
This is not perfect but works, but still looking for a better way to do this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").Slicers(1).SlicerCache.ClearAllFilters
        For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems.Count
            If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems(i).Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("A1") Then
               ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Test").SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```